# Find maximum condition number of symmetric five-diagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, condition-number

Let $A$ be a five-diagonal matrix:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & b & & \cdots & & & & \\
a & 1 & a  & b&  \cdots & & & & \\
b & a & 1& a & \cdots & & & & \\
 & b & a & 1 & \cdots & & & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 &   &   &   & \cdots & 1 & a & b & \\
 &   &   &   & \cdots & a & 1 & a & b \\
 &   &   &   & \cdots & b & a & 1 & a \\
 &  &   &   & \cdots & & b & a & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}
$$

- $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$
- $0 \le b \le a < \dfrac{1}{2}$
- $A$ is symmetric
- $A$ is positive definite $\Longrightarrow$ all $\lambda > 0$
- $A$ is a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix)

**Question:** What is the maximum condition number of $A$ for all $n$?

$$K(a, b) = \max_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}} \kappa(a, b, n) = \max_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{*} } \dfrac{\lambda_{max}(a, b, n)}{\lambda_{min}(a, b, n)}$$

---

**EDIT:**

> Using a numerical method with many pairs $(a, \ b)$, I found that $\kappa(a, \ b, \ n)$ is a monotonically non-increasing function (with respect to $n$).
>
> $$\kappa(a, b, 1) \le \kappa(a, b, 2) \le \cdots \le \kappa(a, \ b, \ n) \le \kappa(a, \ b, \ n+1) \le \cdots$$
>
> $$K(a, \ b) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \kappa(a, \ b, \ n)$$
>
> Some values of conditions number are:
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \kappa(a, \ b, \ 1) = 1$$
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & a \\ a & 1\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \kappa(a, \ b, \ 1) = \dfrac{1+a}{1-a}$$
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b \\ a & 1 & a \\ b & a & 1\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \kappa(a, \ b, \ 1) = \dfrac{1+\frac{1}{2}\left(b+\sqrt{b^2+8a^2}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{2}\left(b-\sqrt{b^2+8a^2}\right)}$$
>
> Like shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), when $b=0$:
> $$\lambda_k = 1+2a\cos \left(\dfrac{k\pi}{n+1}\right) \ \ \ k = 1, \ \cdots, \ n$$
> $$\kappa(a, \ 0, \ n) = \dfrac{1+2a \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)}{1-2a\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)}$$
> $$K(a,  \ 0) = \dfrac{1+2a}{1-2a}$$
> I also found that for $a=0$
>
> $$\lambda_k = 1+2b \cdot \cos \phi_k$$
> $$\kappa(0, \ b, \ n) = \dfrac{1+2b \ \cos \phi_{min}}{1-2b \ \cos \phi_{min}}$$
> $$K(0, \ b) = \dfrac{1+2b}{1-2b}$$

Comment: In general, there is no closed form solution for the eigenvalues of pentadiagonal, Toeplitz matrices. You can express them as solutions to rational equations as described [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379511004307)